# Signing out using Google API not working

Tags: authentication, google-api, logout, google-api-js-client

I followed the instructions in:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Everything works (signing in a user) but I cannot sign out a user. I get the following error :

> Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: gapi.auth2 has been
>   initialized with different options

It fails when executing :

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();
```

(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user)

I need code examples to sign out the user from my web application and also to sign the user completely from the Google account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gapi.auth2.init(); was called before by

```
<div class="g-signin2">
```

which uses gapi.auth2. You should call

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
```

instead of gapi.auth2.init(). Full example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @jarosław-gomułka I followed google api instructions but I can't customize scope... please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879227

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

If you set it up according to these instructions you can sign out a user by calling

```
gapi.auth.signOut();
```

Comment: gapi.auth and gapi.auth2 are different libraries, methods from gapi.auth may not necessarily work with gapi.auth2.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this code from web server (ex: Apache, Node.js). The Google Sign In API not working if you directly access files (ex: index.html)